# Email Verification Laravel 8

Tags: email, smtp, verification, email-verification, laravel-8

i am using **laravel 8 and trying to verify my email at the time of registration
and getting error**

> **Cannot send message without a sender address**

as [this is error i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07X7X.png)
here is my **SMTP setting in .env file**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=abc@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=admin@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

and here is my **user model** code

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;


class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable,HasRoles;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
   
   
}
```

and this is my **route from web.php**

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your port or you can do `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0):

Go to folder vendor\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php and then change $options = []; to $options['ssl'] = array('verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true);

I found the solutions here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/stream-socket-enable-crypto-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-laravel-7. Its work for me.